Send api key from a django template
I have a backend application with django, hosted in lightsail and using api gateway to manage it.
The entire backend application is protected by the API key, this means I need to send an api key on each request, this is only for post opperations, for GET the api key is not necessari.
so, in my urls.py i set an index view which serves my template, a simple form with a send button.
this send button will actually send a request to the backend application, but as this is a POST, it needs an api key.
I cannot load the api key as a context because if I console.log() the api key will be exposed, tearing down all the protection for POST operations.
is there a way to send a POST operation with the API key avoiding it to be seen from the index? both the index and the backend operations live in the same django project.
I have tried sending it as context
    api_key = settings.API_KEY
    context = {'api_key': api_key}
    return render(request, "index.html", context)

but printing it from the browser's console it actually prints the api key, it should be hidden but still able to be sent.
